# What does 4th argument of main function in C point to?

Tags: c++, c, arguments, program-entry-point

We have

```
int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envc)
```

for the ordinary. but I want to know if there is any other argument main can have instead of these. And if there is any, what does it point to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, heres the breakdown:

- `argc` -- C standard
- `argv` -- C standard
- `env` -- Works on most UNIX and MS Win, but not standard
- `apple` -- Other information passed as forth argument by Mac OSX and Darwin

Comment: thnaks . helped me a lot. I was compiling the code with arbitrary arguments on Intel x86 Ubuntu 12.04 and the result was wierd . Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

The answers differ in C and in C++:

- In C++, `main` must always return `int`. Every implementation must accept `()` and `(int, char**)` signatures. An implementation *may* accept any other signature. *If* an accepted signature begins with `int, char**, ...`, those *should* have the usual meaning. (Also, `main` gets C linkage, mustn't be overloaded, mustn't be a template, and mustn't be called.)
- In C, `main` may take any form. However, every implementation must accept `int(void)` and `int(int, char**)` types.

As you have noticed, one popular signature supported by certain environments, and conforming with these guidelines, is `int main(int argc, char * argv[], char * env[])`, in which the third argument contains a pointer to the environment. Other extensions are conceivable; check the documentation of your platform.

Comment: for the records, in C freestanding environments may have an implementation defined return type different than `int`.

Comment: @JensGustedt: A freestanding environment needn't have `main` at all, neither in C nor in C++. Everything I said applies to hosted environments only.

Answer (score 3):

Only argc and argv are standard arguments.  Anything after that depends on your system and compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I think this answers your question:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function#C_and_C.2B.2B

Answer (score 1):

It is an extension to the standard:
But it is supposed to provide access to the environment:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envc)
{
    // It is an array of pointers to C-String
    // The array is terminated with a NULL pointer.
    // So you can loop over with it like this.
    for(int loop = 0;envc[loop] != NULL; ++loop)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", envc[loop]);
    }
}
```

- argc: number of valid elements in argv
- argv: an array of C-Strings for the command line arguments.
- envc: an array of C-Strings for the environment (terminated by NULL pointer).

It is probably better to use `getenv`:

```
char * getenv ( const char * name );
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/getenv/